# Mysql INSERT and DELETE

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a MySql table "Phrases" :

```
PHRASES
  phrase
```

Here are some examples of phrases:

```
"The quick brown fo"
"Eeney Meeney"
```

When inserting a new phrase in the table, I would like to check first to see if any of the existing rows are a partial version of the phrase to be inserted.  If so, then that row gets deleted.

For example, if I insert "Eeney Meeney Miney Moe" and the table already contains "Eeney Meeney", then "Eeney Meeney" will get deleted along with the insert, and the table will only contain "Eeney Meeney Miney Moe"

What is the most efficient way to do this?  Is it possible to do this in pure SQL?

Comment: I think you'll want to thoroughly think out your requirements for something like this related to "partial version of phrases".  If you replaced "Eeney Meeney" with "Eeney Meeney Miney Moe", could it then be replaced again in the opposite direction?  would phrases like "a" replace anything containing the string "a" with only "a"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Triggers to achieve the result.

On Insert Trigger, you can check the phrases and delete which ever are matching.

Answer (score 0):

Using a transaction you could apply an update and if it doesn't exist use an insert.